# How to speed up my code in cleaning documents in NLP problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wrote a small function to clean up text document. The function would take off any words that have length less than 2, it will remove all special characters and all words entirely made of digits and also stop words with a custom list. it will also do a simple spell check and remove all the "fake words". However, the function runs super slow and I am wondering any ways to speed it up.

```py
def clean_up_phrases_no_stopwords_no_short_letters_no_numeric(kx):
    kx=" ".join([x for x in kx.split(" ") if len(x)>2])
    kx=" ".join([x for x in kx.split(" ") if x not in total_stopword])    
    kx=" ".join(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', x) for x in kx.split(" "))    
    kx=" ".join([x for x in kx.split(" ") if not x.isdigit()])
    filted_fake_words=list(filter(None, [return_valid_word(x) for x in kx.split(" ") ]))    
    kx=" ".join(filted_fake_words)        
    return kx

def return_valid_word(word):
    word_token=word.split(" ")
    word_token=list(filter(None, word_token))
    word_list=list()
    for x in word_token:
        word_list.append(lemma_single_word(x))

    if len([x for x in word_list if x in word_set])>0:
        return word
    else:
        filtered_word=[return_valid_single_nondict_word(x) for x in word_list]
        if filtered_word==[None]:
            return None
        else:
            word=" ".join([return_valid_single_nondict_word(x) for x in word_list])
            return word

def return_valid_single_nondict_word(word):
    character=list(word)
    max_character_num=Counter(character).most_common(1)[0][1]
    if max_character_num > 3:
        return None
    else:
        return word

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using nltk. It'll simplify the process.

Sample code:

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

data = "... your text here ..."

stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
tokens = word_tokenize(data)
resultset = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
```

Add extra filters to remove other words you'd like to discard.

Comment: nltk only solves the stop_words, whatabout the rest of the clean up ?

Comment: It was an example. Rest would be implemented  almost as the same. Nltk is the go to solution for nlp in python. Have a look at what it has to offer. Basically, it fulfills almost  all of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Top time eating in your code is **data copying**. `x for x in kx.split(" ")` is just generator, but you force to copy data every time when do  `kx=" ".join(`, `word_token=list(`, `list(filter(`. Therefore you should write code the way to minimize data copying.

In this particular case you can use once `x for x in kx.split(" ")` as follow:

```
def clean_up_phrases_no_stopwords_no_short_letters_no_numeric(phrase):
    filtered_words=[]
    for word in phrase.split(" "):
       if not len(word)>2: continue # continue, so just skip this word
       if word in total_stopword: continue
       word = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', word) # modification of word
       if word.isdigit(): continue
       if not is_lemma_single_word(word): continue
       if not is_valid_single_nondict_word(word): continue
       filtered_words.append(word)
    return " ".join(filtered_x)
```

In this case you should rewrite your word test functions to return True or False, not word or None.

And here still some place to farther optimizing, for example, not to gather filtered_word but resulting string, etc.